# importance of ordering of operands in Java's ==

Tags: java

Sorry to keep asking the basics but I don't understand this simple code and why the first print statement goes through the compiler ok and even prints true, but the second print statement doesn't compile, giving me an "incomparable types" error:

```
int in1 = 38;
Number Nn1 = in1;
System.out.println(in1 == Nn1);
System.out.println(Nn1 == in1);
```

I am not expecting this result, I thought it was pretty standard that == was symmetric?

I am using javac 1.6.0_26 and also NetBeans but get the same result, the first println statement compiles without problem and the second does not..

Comment: From people's comments to Maciej's answer, it looks like there was a change made to the semantics of unboxing in Java 7 and back-ported to later updates of the Java 6 compiler?

Comment: I also think this is essentially a bit of "Java pub trivia" -- I seriously doubt it is likely to crop up in actual production code.

Comment: I use jdk1.7.0_03 on Windows.

Comment: I have a similar situation when assigning to Object (instead of Number). I'm surprised about the lack of symmetry?

Comment: OK, see my answer-- I've tried to explain concretely why this actually violates the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that, according to the Java Language Specification, neither way round should compile.

It's important firstly to understand that **auto(un)boxing is only applied to expressions that meet certain criteria, and only for specific wrapper classes** (Integer, Long etc, not Number).

Now, in the case of ==, autounboxing is applied specifically when **one is of
[primitive] numeric type and the other is convertible to [primitive] numeric type** (JLS 15.12.1) according to the rules. And as we've just stated, "according to the rules", **Number is not convertible to a numeric primitive type**.

It is NOT, the case, for example, that the int should be converted to an Integer and then a reference comparison made: **autoboxing is not specified to be applied to an == reference comparison** (JLS 15.21.3).

So if your compiler is allowing the cited code to compile, **it does not obey the Java Language Specification**.

This behaviour makes sense because to perform a numeric comparison, the **compiler needs to know the actual specific type** of both operands in order to **perform numeric promotion**. You might think that you can compare, say, a Number with an integer, and that the compiler should just call .intValue() on the Number. But this is inappropriate, because if the original number type was actually a Float, then the correct comparison is actually to first convert the integer to a Float rather than the other way round. In other words, **with a Number, the compiler doesn't have all the information to correctly perform a numeric comparison with a primitive**.

Comment: Thanks for making this detailed case. What is the next step, report the behavior as a bug and wait for them to accept it or reject it?

Comment: Having read your reply I have a follow up question. What about this code, it compiles also but should it? If so, how is that different? 
 ArrayList<Number> aln = new ArrayList<Number>();
 aln.add((byte)3);
 aln.add(5.0);
 aln.add(8L);

Comment: in the third paragraph of your reply you refer to 15.21.3. If autoboxing is not specified to be applied to an == reference comparison, does this not imply that (anint == anInteger) should also fail? We do agree that (anInteger == aNumber) should be possible, and by your arguments (anint == aNumber) should not be possible. If (anint == anInteger) were possible, would it not kill the transitive property of equality?

Comment: *"... does this not imply that (anint == anInteger) should also fail?"*.  No, because `Integer` IS convertible to a numeric primitive type.

Comment: *"...would it not kill the transitive property of equality"*.  No.  The transitivity property only applies to the results of meaningful comparisons that are allowed by the type system.  If you try to extend it to cases where the comparison gives a compile time or runtime error, you are liable to get nonsensical results.  And even within that constraint, consider the case of comparing NaN values...

Comment: @StephenC Assuming you and Neil are right then I believe the answer has to be that anint can be equal to aNumber but to express this requires a cast of anint to (Integer). I've checked JDK 5 6 and 7 javacs and Java 5 and 6 are asymmetric as I wrote but 7 allows both forms. You may be right but Java seems to be evolving *closer* to what you and Neil are saying it should not be doing. So what is the answer? Also, I do not understand your reference to NaN: equality operations with NaN are transitive I think since they always return false?

Comment: @Mishax - 1) You are right about NaN's.  2) A cast of `anInt` to (integer) would cause satisfy the compiler, but it would result in semantically incorrect code.  Comparing two `Integer` instances using `==` is generally incorrect.

Comment: @StephenC I agree that == is not a substitute for "equals". I would compare an autoboxed int with another Integer using == to determine if the other reference was interned. Comparison with == is still faster than comparison with equals so for small values I see a usefulness there.

Comment: @Mishax Performance-wise, there's really probably not terribly much in it. I would wait until you have a case where there is a demonstrable performance improvement; having == that effectively has one semantics with small (interned) numbers and another with larger (non-interned) numbers is just asking for trouble with no measurable performance benefit whatsoever in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

My compiler (`jdk1.7.0_03` on Windows) says that both lines are incorrect:

[image]

> Operator == cannot be applied to `int` and `java.lang.Number`

Comment: Same here, using Eclipse and JDK 1.6. Which compiler did the question author use?

Comment: @Maciej why wouldnt in1 get Boxed into Integer wrapper ??

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing -- I wouldn't expect either to compile: autoboxing works with specific types (Integer, Double etc) but not if the variable is simply declared as a Number.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't get it autounboxed because the compiler doesn't *strictly* know what to autounbox it to. Unless this behaviour has changed in the very latest release or something...?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Provided that you have a specific number type, it's fine.

Comment: @NeilCoffey awesome, as you said it wouldnt work in java 7 .. :)

Comment: I've added an answer explaining why allowing either line to compile would actually violate the language specification. It really does look like it's just a buggy compiler.

Answer (score 1):

When you check for equality between an `int` and an `Integer`, unboxing occurs.
In fact, compiler is aware that `Integer` operand wraps only `int`. It's like a clue.

However, `Number`, although implemented by `Integer` (and others), is too generic and would expect too much job for compiler to extract the original primitive type in order to operate the unboxing.

Hence, compiler complains about it and expects you a more fine-grained type.

Comment: Mik, that is correct. But my problem is with the lack of symmetry of the == operator and that the ordering of the operands seems to have an effect on the result.

Comment: @Mishax I use IntelliJ with a Java 7 JDK, with `Number`, compiler complains about both lines, not only one... logic. Have you tried to compile your code with command-line, without IDE? Maybe it's a temporary issue with your IDE.

Comment: thanks, yes I have closed my IDE and started on the command line 32bit javac from jdk1.6.0_32 and 64 bit javac from jdk1.6.0_26. I get the same results - the first one compiles and the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Both lines are a compile error. If not, there's a bug in NetBeans.

If you change `Number` to `Integer`, both lines compile.

```
int in1 = 38;
Integer Nn1 = in1; // Changed to Integer
System.out.println(in1 == Nn1); // compiles
System.out.println(Nn1 == in1); // compiles
```

Comment: This is what I expected, but see some of the other comments -- people are apparently reporting that it does compile in certain compiler versions...!?!

Comment: I'd like to add in case it wasn't clear, not only does the first line compile in NetBeans, it also compiles in javac. Not only that, it runs. Not only that, it doesn't throw an error when it runs. Not only that, it returns TRUE when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing values reference-type values with primitive values, the only way it could work would be because of an auto unboxed conversion. But that type of conversion doesn't seem to be specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

It probably not symmetric because it's not intended to be possible at all. Maybe a compiler bug.